# maven-scala-plugin error running scala code in a Maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create my first "Hello World" Scala project using Maven as the build tool and IntelliJ as my IDE. I keep getting the following error when running `mvn package`.

```
Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile
```

Here is the full error: 
Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) on project couchbase-test-3: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1)

Here is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>couchbase-test-3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.7.0</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

The JDK I'm using is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home.

The code I'm trying to run is just to print out "Hello World!":

```
package org.example

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
object App extends Application {
  println( "Hello World!" )
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You probably want to use `App` instead of `Application` and name your own object something else.

Comment: Could you post full stack trace for `Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile` error? It should point to the particular line of code, that has the problem.

Comment: @RayanRal This is the full error (I also updated the question itself): `Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) on project couchbase-test-3: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1)`

Comment: Do you have to use scala `2.7.0` and your maven scala plugin has `-target:jvm-1.5` argument. Scala 2.7.0 should not be compatible with Java 1.5.

Comment: @SašaZejnilović Should the target be `-target:jvm-1.8`?

Comment: Ok, I am looking at it and you just want to get any scala running. Use maven archetype, for example [this](https://github.com/davidB/scala-archetype-simple). This GH Readme will help you.

Comment: @user This may be a silly question. I'm brand new to Scala so forgive me but what exactly do you mean by use `App` instead of `Application`? I believe that part of the code was automatically generated by IntelliJ...

Comment: @eTothEipiPlus1 I meant that the trait `scala.Application` is now deprecated, and you are recommended to use `scala.App`, so your object should look something like `object SomeName extends App`. However, if it was generated by IntelliJ, you might have an older version of the plugin? That's very confusing to me

Comment: Is this resolved ? i am also facing the same.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to create the Scala project from scratch again, you can follow this link to build a simple Scala project with Maven:

[Creating the most basic Scala project with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047186/creating-the-most-basic-scala-project-with-maven)

Another option would be, when you are creating a Scala project with Maven you can choose an archetype for scala projects, and clean from the pom.xml what you don't need, that worked for me.

[image]

On the other hand you could choose SBT to create Scala projects. SBT is very easy and fully integrated with IntelliJ Idea, so you can create a SBT project in IntlliJ and make up the build.sbt file yourself and put in it the scala version you want, compile, package and execute with SBT.

As an example

```
name := "my_first_scala_app"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP3" % Test
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn’t exactly solve the OP’s problem. What if they have a requirement at work or something?

Comment: I changed my answer. I hope this helps.